# single action by using multiple buttons in android

Tags: android

single action by using multiple buttons in android for example by pressing button1 and button2 we get a single action.
what is will be the best method for solving this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.braill);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    Button complete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.complete);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    complete.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext);
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn1 & R.id.btn2 & R.id.complete:
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
        toast.show();
        edittext.append("a");
        break;  
    }


}
```

}}

Answer (score 1):

turn your switch into a valid if condintion

```
if ( (v.getId()==R.id.btn1) || (v.getId()==R.id.btn2) || (v.getId()==R.id.complete))
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
    toast.show();
    edittext.append("a");
    break;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place all the button in a case statement, Don't add **break** with them and at the last case statement just add your logic and place **break** statement.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext);
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1: 
                 //no break; continue executing next.
        case R.id.btn2: 
              //no break; continue executing next.
        case R.id.complete:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
            toast.show();
            edittext.append("a");
//break here.
            break;  
    ...
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

> button3333.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(button3333));
>   button2222.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(button2222));

the implementation for ***getOnClickDoSomething(***)

```
View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
return new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("text now set.. ");    
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd introduce an anonymous instance of OnClickListener, which you can set as a listener to the relevant buttons. This encapsulates the behaviour nicely and you won't have to cross reference the button ID's:

```
private OnClickListener mDoWhatever = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
        toast.show();
        edittext.append("a");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.braill);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    Button complete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.complete);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(mDoWhatever);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(mDoWhatever);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    complete.setOnClickListener(mDoWhatever);
  }
```